# One parameter subgroups of a Lie subgroup

Tags: lie-groups

Suppose $H$ is a closed connected Lie subgroup of $G$. Are one parameter subgroups of $H$ also one parameter subgroups of $G$? If not true in general, when is the statement true?

Comment: Of course, any subgroup of $H$ is also a subgroup of $G$.  The fact that it's a "one parameter subgroup" also still holds in the larger context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a $1$-parameter subgroup of $G$ is a Lie group homomorphism $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to G$. If $H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$ and $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to H$ a $1$-parameter subgroup of $H$, then the composition
$$i\circ\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to H\overset{i}{\hookrightarrow} G$$
is a $1$-parameter subgroup of $G$ since the inclusion $i:H\hookrightarrow G$ is a Lie group homomorphism and a composition of Lie group homomorphisms is a Lie group homomorphism.